# Draw non-uniform B-spline in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the couple of spline curves in Latex. Is there anything I could use in tikz or other packages such that I could draw a spline curve by simply providing the control points value and knots vector?

Comment: I know about nothing on splines, but you might take a look at the pstricks `pst-bspline` package.

Comment: If you tell us what one is, somebody can probably help you draw one. But a minimal example of what you've got so far would be much better. Especially if you need TikZ because this is part of a larger figure, say. Otherwise, why the obsession with TikZ? Enquiring minds need to know!

Comment: my guess is that NURBS are not supported by the postscript language (and the pdf counterpart) and does exist neither in Tikz nor in pstricks.

Comment: You may find this article useful: [Howto: Draw algebraic curves using PGF/TikZ](https://pbelmans.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/howto-draw-algebraic-curves-using-pgftikz/).

Comment: With TikZ or PSTricks, you can draw cubic Bézier curves...

Comment: The [smooth] option uses a quadratic spline (piecewise continuous in slope) with tension to resolve the one degree of freedom.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Are you sure?

Comment: @Paul Gaborit - The code definitely uses piecewise quadratics and is smooth (continuous slope).  By definition, that is a quadratic spline.,

Comment: @JohnKormylo With TiKZ and pgf (as with PDF), all curves (circle, arc, ellipse, sin, curveto, etc.) are cubic Bézier curves. Even `\pgfpathquadraticcurveto` uses cubic Bézier curves.

Answer (score 1):

The pgfmanual on CTAN describes curved path contructions in chapter 2.4 on page 31.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw [gray] (0,0) circle [radius=2pt]
(1,1) circle [radius=2pt]
(2,1) circle [radius=2pt]
(2,0) circle [radius=2pt];
\draw (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (2,1) .. (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Also, *48.3 Path Replacing Decorations*, pg 584, in TikZ Manual for Version 3.0.1a.